# Delete records based on another query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query in `MySQL` based on which I am finding duplicate records of some columns.

```
select max(id), count(*) as cnt 
from table group by start_id, end_id, mysqltable 
having cnt>1;
```

This above query gives me the `max(id)` and the count of number of records that have `start_id,end_id,mysqltable` column values same.

I want to delete all the records that match the `max(id)` column of the above query

How can I do that?

I have tried like below

```
delete from table 
where (select max(id), count(*) as cnt 
from table group by start_id,end_id,mysqltable 
having cnt>1)
```

But Unable to delete records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicate records using JOIN.

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1
INNER JOIN
  table t2
WHERE 
t1.id > t2.id AND t1.start_id = t2.start_id AND  t1.end_id = t2.end_id AND t1.mysqltable = t2.mysqltable;
```

This query keeps the lowest id and remove the highest.

Answer (score 1):

I think so this command should work:

```
  delete from table 
    where id in  
    ( select max(id) from table 
         group by start_id, end_id, mysqltable 
         having count(*) > 1 
    );
```